# Como extrair todos nomes de td em ordem?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Eu preciso extrair todos os nomes de pessoas nesse site:

[Camara.gov.br](http://www.camara.gov.br/proposicoesWeb/prop_emendas?idProposicao=2122076&subst=0)

Escrevi esse código em Python3:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request, urllib.parse, urllib.error

emendas = urlopen("http://www.camara.gov.br/proposicoesWeb/prop_emendas?idProposicao=2122076&subst=0")

bsObje =  BeautifulSoup(emendas, "lxml")

tabelas = bsObje.findAll("tbody", {"class":"coresAlternadas"})

deputados = []

for linha in tabelas:
    deputados.append(linha.select('td')[3].text.strip())

print(deputados)
Resultado -> ['Laura Carneiro', 'André Figueiredo']
```

Não deu certo. Por favor, alguém sabe como faço para pegar todos os nomes em ordem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Qual é a ordem que desejas? Alfabética ou pela ordem em que foram encontrados?

Em baixo faço para cobrir os dois cenários:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
from urllib.request import urlopen

req = urlopen('http://www.camara.gov.br/proposicoesWeb/prop_emendas?idProposicao=2122076&subst=0')
soup = bs(req.read(), 'html.parser')

tables_ele = soup.findAll('tbody', {'class': 'coresAlternadas'})
deputados = []
for table_ele in tables_ele:
    for row in table_ele.findAll('tr'):
        cols = row.findAll('td')
        deputados.append(cols[3].text.strip())

print(deputados) # pela ordem encontrados na tabela
```

Depois para ordenar alfabéticamente podes:

```
...
deputados = sorted(deputados)
```

Para remover duplicados, (há muitos duplicados) e ordenar alfabéticamente podes converter a lista em um [set](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets) e ordenar depois:

```
...
deputados = sorted(set(deputados))
```

Comment: Obrigado, deu certo. Mas se eu quiser extrair também o último lote de ('tbody', {'class': 'coresAlternadas'}), que tem mais 32 nomes na coluna Autor. Faço um find só desse lote? Como?

Comment: @ReinaldoChaves, ha percebi, há duas `tbody`, sendo que o ultimo é o PLENÁRIO, queres os nomes dessa também?

Comment: Editado para isso @ReinaldoChaves.

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que vi na tabela, os próprios nomes lá não estão ordenados..

Então você pode capturá-los normalmente, e no final, com toda a lista capturada ordenar eles via python, usando o comando `sorted` na lista, ou então somente o método `.sort()` ( esse sem atribuir à variável ) , já que ele opera sobre a lista.

> Usando o sorted

```
>>> deputados = sorted(deputados)
>>> deputados
['André Figueiredo', 'Laura Carneiro']
```

> Usando o .sort()

```
>>> deputados.sort()
>>> deputados
['André Figueiredo', 'Laura Carneiro']
```